# Let S = {1,2....10} Let R be the relation on P(S), the power set of S, defined by: for any X,Y ∈ P(S),

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

Let S = {1,2....10} Let R be the relation on P(S), the power set of S, defined by: for any X,Y ∈ P(S),

XRY <=> X∩Y=∅

is it true that ∀X∈P(S),∃Y∈P(S) so that (X,Y)∈R?

I dont know what is (X,Y)?

how many sets X∈P(S) are there so that XR{10}? help me on this one please

Comment: Can you tell me which (if any) of the following three ordered pairs of subsets of $S$ are in $R$? $$\langle\{1,3\},\rangle\{2,5,6\}\rangle,\langle\{1,3\},\{2,3,6\}\rangle,\langle\{1,3\},\varnothing\rangle$$

Comment: ⟨{1,3},{2,5,6}⟩, ⟨‌​{1,3},∅⟩?

Comment: Good. Yes, that’s right. So if $X\,R\,\{10\}$, that means that $X\cap\{10\}=\varnothing$, which means that $10\notin X$. Can you say how many subsets of $S$ there are that do not contain $10$?

Comment: The exponent is right: it’s $a^9$ for **some** $a$, but $a$ isn’t $9$. When you build a set that doesn’t include $10$, you have to make a two-way choice for each of the numbers $1,2,\ldots,9$: either the number is in the set that you’re building, or it isn’t. How many ways are there to make $9$ two-way choices in a row?

Comment: I don't think I understand it :\. Is (2,7,8,9)∈X? Also, is it 2^9?

Comment: There is no fixed $X$. Your goal is to count the subsets of $S$ that do not contain $10$. One of these sets is $\{2,7,8,9\}$, but that’s just one of many. The subsets of $S$ that don’t contain $10$ are precisely the subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. How many subsets does this $9$-element set have?

Comment: $9 \choose 9$ +$9 \choose 8$ ......+$9\choose 1$?

Comment: Plus $\binom90$, since the empty set is also a subset of $\{1,\ldots,9\}$. Yes, but that’s **really** doing it the hard way. A set of $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets: building a subset is like going down the line of $n$ elements and saying *yes, you’re in* or *no, you’re not in* to each in turn. There are $$\underbrace{2\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot 2}_{n\text{ twos}}=2^n$$ different sequences of *yes* and *no*, so there are $2^n$ different subsets that can be formed. So how many subsets does $\{1,\ldots,9\}$ have?

Comment: I think it is 2^9

Comment: There you go! Yes, that’s right, and those $2^9$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,9\}$ are exactly the subsets of $S$ that don’t contain $10$. This means that they are exactly the sets $X\in\wp(S)$ such that $X\,R\,\{10\}$. And now you know how many there are.

Comment: Thank you for helping me step by step

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the power set of $S$ is the set of all possible subsets of $S$. So if $X\in P(S)$, what set is also in $P(S)$ that has no elements of $X$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $X$ has some elements.  What happens if $Y$ has any of them?